# Odd Python zip() behavior

Tags: python, debugging, zip, generator, xrange

I am working with generators in Python, and I am getting odd behavior. I am not entirely how to phrase the question...

My code performs a pattern search over an objective function. The issue I see shows up when I `zip` the results of my `patternSearch` generator with an `xrange` to get only the first 12 results. It seems as though the `xmin` component of the tuple returned by my generator is repeated over the length of the zip. What is especially weird, the `ymin` component of the same tuple is not repeated. When I initialize a generator object `ps` and call `ps.next()` repeatedly, the results are correct.

What could be the issue?? Thanks!

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

def obj(x):
   x1,x2 = x
   return 100*(x2 - x1**2)**2 + (1 - x1)**2

# fobj: objective function of vector x
#   x0: initial point
#    h: initial step size
#    r: reduction parameter
def patternSearch(fobj,x0,h,r):
   n = len(x0) # get dimensionality
   dims = range(0,n)
   # initialize given x0
   xmin = list(x0)
   ymin = fobj(xmin)

   yield (xmin,ymin) # send back the initial condition first

   while True:
      focus = True
      for i in dims:
         x = xmin # start from the last best point
         x[i] += h
         y = fobj(x) # eval
         if y < ymin:
            ymin = y
            xmin = x
            focus = False
            continue
         # else, y > ymin
         x[i] -= 2*h # go in the opposite direction
         y = fobj(x) # eval
         if y < ymin:
            ymin = y
            xmin = x
            focus = False
            continue
         # else, no update to this dim
      if focus:
         h *= r
      yield (xmin,ymin)

def main():
   x0 = (3,5)
   imax = 12
   print 'Initial condition: ', x0
   print 'Stop condition: i == ', imax
   print 'Iteration |     x1     |     x2     |      y     '
   for (x,y), i in zip(patternSearch(obj,x0,h=0.5,r=0.5), xrange(imax)):
      print "{:>9} | {:<10} | {:<10} | {:<11}".format(i,x[0],x[1],y)

   print 'Generator output test:'
   g = patternSearch(obj,x0,0.5,0.5)
   for i in xrange(imax):
      g.next()
```

## Output

```
Initial condition:  (3, 5)
Stop condition: i ==  12
Iteration |     x1     |     x2     |      y     
        0 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1604       
        1 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 58.5       
        2 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 58.5       
        3 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.953125   
        4 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.953125   
        5 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.2900390625
        6 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.2900390625
        7 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.13043212891
        8 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.13043212891
        9 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.06357192993
       10 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.06357192993
       11 | 2.0        | 4.03125    | 1.03150010109
Generator output test:
([3, 5], 1604)
([2.5, 5.5], 58.5)
([2.0, 5.0], 58.5)
([2.25, 4.75], 1.953125)
([2.0, 4.5], 1.953125)
([2.125, 4.375], 1.2900390625)
([2.0, 4.25], 1.2900390625)
([2.0625, 4.1875], 1.13043212890625)
([2.0, 4.125], 1.13043212890625)
([2.03125, 4.09375], 1.0635719299316406)
([2.0, 4.0625], 1.0635719299316406)
([2.015625, 4.046875], 1.0315001010894775)
```

Comment: "*`zip` the results of my `patternSearch` generator with an `xrange`*" - no love for `enumerate`?

Comment: I thought this was an easier way to terminate than `if i > imax: break`

Answer (score 1):

You reuse the list `xmax` and change their elements, but it is always the same list, so the zipped list consists of 12 times the same list.
The generator seems to work, because the list is printed for each step.

Replace the line

```
x = xmin
```

with

```
x = list(xmin)
```

Comment: Except the generator works fine on its own. Look at the output.

Comment: @abatea: answer extended

Comment: Alright, thanks for the pointer! I changed my yield line to `yield(list(xmin),ymin)`, and that solved the problem. So before, each item in the zip was pointing to the same list object.

Comment: The odd thing is, shouldn't the zip be evaluating only when called, just like the generator? My code still should be printing once per iteration, rather than evaluating the entire list first, right?

Comment: @abatea it depends on the version of Python you use. In Py 3 `zip` is a generator, in Py 2 you need to rely on `itertools.izip` for that. Since there is `xrange` in your code, you are on Py 2.

Comment: @abatea: i've shown you the line, where you have to do the correction. Otherwise, your results may be wrong either way.